# Laravel, Angular 7, JWT cookie storage

Tags: angular, laravel, cookies, jwt, angular7

I have a requirement to implement JWT authentication on an application and I'm trying to mitigate as many risks as possible by using cookie storage (httpOnly) instead of localStorage.

A Laravel server is set up as an API and *does not* serve the Angular 7 app. The login controller response with the following:

`return response()->json($user)->cookie('access_token', $token, 15, '/', true, true);`

I can see the cookie (token=blahblahblah) in my response after a `POST` request to the login URL. I've set `withCredentials: true` in all requests following the login. I might be wildly misunderstanding this but I want that cookie to be sent along with every subsequent request to authenticate my now logged in user. My middleware in Laravel is looking for `$request->cookie('access_token')` which is always empty.

Is this even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HttpInterceptor and send your token in the 'Authorization' header, it will be executed with every request.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
// Clone the request to add the new header
const clonedRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'YOUR_TOKEN') });

// Pass the cloned request instead of the original request to the next handle
return next.handle(clonedRequest);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel You can use the Cookie facade to "queue" cookies for attachment to the outgoing response from your application.

**The queue method accepts a Cookie instance or the arguments needed to create a Cookie instance. These cookies will be attached to the outgoing response before it is sent to the browser**:

```
Cookie::queue('name', 'value', $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
```

ref: [Laravel doc for cookies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#cookies)